# How do I reply to a message outside of the channel I typed in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I've created a command that is supposed to reply to a user's message.
Here's my code so far (check_perms() is a separate function to check if a user has the proper permissions to run the command):

```
@client.command()
async def reply(ctx, message_id:discord.Message=None, *, message=None):
    if await check_perms(ctx):
        if not message_id is None:
            try:
                await message_id.channel.trigger_typing()
                await asyncio.sleep(len(message)/10)
                await message_id.reply(message)
                await ctx.message.add_reaction('\N{White Heavy Check Mark}')
            except:
                await ctx.message.add_reaction('\N{Cross Mark}')
        else:
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=embed_colors['red'],description=f'\N{Cross Mark} Missing message id or message input.'))
```

The two inputs in the command are first the message's id and the content for the reply. The error that I get when attempting to reply to a message outside of the channel I send the command in is:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MessageNotFound: Message "802311267649716224" not found.
```

Both channels are in the same server. Is there a way to locate the message outside of the channel I am sending the command in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gonna have to get the `TextChannel` instance first, then you can either use the `fetch_message` or `get_partial_message` method

```py
channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
# Getting the message by making an API call
message = await channel.fetch_message(MESSAGE_ID)
# Getting the message from cache
message = channel.get_partial_message(MESSAGE_ID) # Note that this returns a `discord.PartialMessage` instance not `discord.Message`
```

Sadly there's no other way of getting the message instance without first getting the channel

Also note that you need discord.py v1.6+ to use the `TextChannel.get_partial_message` method

#### Reference:

- [`Bot.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel)
- [`TextChannel.fetch_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message)
- [`TextChannel.get_partial_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.get_partial_message)